# Run jar on tomcat via hadoop

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, hadoop, cmd

I have a dynamic web project with tomcat (hadoop is installed). I want to allow users to define an argument for my hadoop application via the website. On the server I then want to run my jar with the provided query argument via hadoop. So basically I want to run the following command on my server:

```
hadoop jar query.jar query
```

Because of hadoop I can not simply use the methods of query.jar in my dynamic web project directly. So i just want the server to run the above command in its cmd. I have placed the query.jar in the WEB-INF/lib folder of my server. I tried the following code in my servlet:

```
String query = request.getParameter("query");
    String execute = "hadoop jar WEB-INF/lib/query.jar " + query;
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execute);
    try {
        process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        System.out.print("Error running jar");
    }
    System.out.print("Execution Successful");
```

And while I always get a "Execution Successful", my hadoop job is never executed on the server. Is the path to my query.jar that I provided in the execute String correct? Are there any other mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

Just because you get `Execution Successful` doesn't mean that it got executed correctly. Change the code as follow.

```
String query = sanitize(request.getParameter("query"));
String hadoopHome = System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME");
if(hadoopHome == null) {
    hadoopHome = "<ABSOLUTE PATH TO HADOOP>";
}
String execute = hadoopHome + "/bin/hadoop jar <ABSOLUTE PATH TO>/query.jar <Class Name> " + query;
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(execute);
int i = -1;
try {
    i = process.waitFor();
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    System.out.print("Error running jar");
}
if(i == 0) {
    System.out.print("Execution Successful");
} else {
    System.out.print("Error running jar");
}
```

Method `sanitize` should remove any malicious code because this is going to run in the Server side.